# Org or com domain for open source project site?

Tags: open-source, seo, dns, domain-name

Let's say I have an open project called Some Project. Would you recommend hosting the project site under someproject.com or someproject.org, and why? I realize that .org suits an open source project better, but I'm afraid that on longer term, I may want to (*cough...*) start making money out of it, and .org would become misleading, while moving to .com could cause troubles in the sense of SEO and promotion. I hope someone could shed some light on this dilemma.

Comment: What's the programming part of this question?  I don't see where this is programming related.  This sounds like business strategy.  Can you clarify this question?

Comment: I agree it has no direct relation to programming techniques, but I find it no less relevant than a question about the future of old developers for example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972611/old-developers-any-future/972627). I do software (I don't sell cars), and I'm willing to hear what's the best way to promote it. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sergei Kozlov: Your question applies equally well to selling cars as it does to programming.  That makes it a poor fit for a site focused narrowly on progrmaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of .org (from various sources) is "top-level Internet domain used by associations and non-profit organizations mostly in the U.S. and Canada." So, this could become misleading (not that people don't do it). I would follow the lead of WordPress, where .org is the Open Source project and .com is the commercial entity.

Answer (score 2):

Register both, use the .org for the open project, save the .com for if/when you need it.

Comment: Also register your country's TLD and .net

Answer (score 2):

Register both. Use .org as the main domain,  .com is supposed to be for commercial ventures but you wouldn't want it to be taken by a domain squatter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what the project is.  For example, .fm is often used for music sites.

Either way, if your project rocks, it doesn't matter.